# Get folder path in ASP.NET page

Tags: asp.net

I am working on an app to extract data and store into database. I create a windows service and start it from asp.net page. The thing I want to do now is to select folder path from my machine and then my windows service can extract data from the files in that folder.

suppose the folder path on my machine is C:\test\data.txt, and in code behind, I get this path through asp.net FileUpload contrl, it may look like the following:

```
string filePath = FileUploadControl.filePath(); //filePath is exactly C:\test\data.txt
```

I did research online, it looks like that I cannot make it by FileUpload control. So I am wondering that if I can walk around this limit? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't read client files 'just like that' on a server. Those are two separate systems and security makes it undesirable to make this possible.